# Why might a compute shader randomly produce different results from unchanged data?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, compute-shader

I have a compute shader that reads pixels from an RWTexture2D texture and, dependent upon which pixels are lit, modifies some RWStructuredBuffer data.

If pixel 1 is lit, it modifies data range A. If pixel 2 is lit, it modifies data range B. Etc, etc...

Most of the time the shader appears to work perfectly. But randomly, some configuration of lit/unlit pixels on the RWTexture2D will cause the shader to randomly modify the wrong data. Change the lit/unlit pixels back to a configuration that worked before and it works again.

The shader isn't multithreaded so there's no read/write fighting. It completes in less than 1ms so it isn't stretching across multiple frames.

Almost certainly this is either (a) a bug in my code, or (b) something fundamental about compute shaders that I've misunderstood. Assuming it's a bug, I've been trying to fix it for days, to the point of rewriting the code.

So I'm hoping this sort of rings a bell with someone? When a compute shader behaves randomly like this, where should I be looking for the error?

Many thanks in advance. Happy to provide more info if needed, I just didn't want to bore people with a long explanation if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. When you Dispatch() multiple kernels sequentially, they run simultaneously. I thought Dispatch() waited for the kernel to finish. I've restructured the code to do everything in one kernel, and it works as intended.